# Bitcoincore listrecievedbyaddress doesn’t work

Tags: bitcoind, testnet

I am trying to run bitcoin full node on testnet. I have downloaded ant started bitcoind with such config:

```
testnet=1
regtest=0
server=1
listen=0
```

I'v generated new address tb1qklst9t8rk97zmwqdq4t8s3dazk3h6rps20y32d
with "getnewaddress" command.

I`v made the transaction from Electrum testnet wallet to this address (transaction id: cefe1ca9048f2fcd42c40b1060cdf4183f98f24eca95a9c499006ee39a033d54).
I can see this transaction in Electrum testnet wallet or on tbtc.bitaps.com.
But results of commands "listreceivedbyaddress 0 true true" and "gettransaction cefe1ca9048f2fcd42c40b1060cdf4183f98f24eca95a9c499006ee39a033d54" are:

```
[
  {
    "address": "tb1qklst9t8rk97zmwqdq4t8s3dazk3h6rps20y32d",
    "amount": 0.00000000,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "label": "",
    "txids": [
    ]
  }
]
```

and

```
error code: -5
error message:
Invalid or non-wallet transaction id
```

The result of "getblockchaininfo" is:

```
{
  "chain": "test",
  "blocks": 626786,
  "headers": 1774117,
  "bestblockhash": "0000000000007d5ba9c09c8ddfa2cc31195aea3fc6e351969bc6fe454d2c29b8",
  "difficulty": 65536,
  "mediantime": 1450388529,
  "verificationprogress": 0.4003797270985711,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007049211b48a78f895",
  "size_on_disk": 4446006159,
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": {
    "bip34": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 21111
    },
    "bip66": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 330776
    },
    "bip65": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": true,
      "height": 581885
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 770112
    },
    "segwit": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 834624
    }
  },
  "warnings": ""
}
```

Bitcoin core version is 0.20.0.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction was mined in block 1773944.

Your node has only synced up to block 626786.

Once your node has synced block 1773944, you should be able to see the transaction.